# Why is Marshal.WriteInt64 method's code so complex?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unsafe

The code below is been reflected form .Net Framework:

```
[SecurityCritical]
public static unsafe void WriteInt64(IntPtr ptr, int ofs, long val){
    try{
        byte* numPtr = (byte*) (((void*) ptr) + ofs);
        if ((((int) numPtr) & 7) == 0){
            *((long*) numPtr) = val;
        }
        else{
            byte* numPtr2 = (byte*) &val;
            numPtr[0] = numPtr2[0];
            numPtr[1] = numPtr2[1];
            numPtr[2] = numPtr2[2];
            numPtr[3] = numPtr2[3];
            numPtr[4] = numPtr2[4];
            numPtr[6] = numPtr2[6];
            numPtr[7] = numPtr2[7];
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException){
        throw new AccessViolationException();
    }
}
```

In my opinion, `*((long*) numPtr) = val` is enough, and very efficient.

Why so complex?

Comment: Maybe something to do with endiens?.

Comment: Looks more like it's to do with memory alignment to me.

Comment: That's memcpy(), unrolled by hand.  Necessary on ARM cores, I think.

Answer (score 6):

It seems rather straightforward, although optimized.

Notice the outer if - it checks to see if you can write the Int64 in one operation (that happens if the pointer you hand the method is aligned properlty - points to the start of an Int64 in memory - the address needs to be a multiple of 8).

If you can't write in one operation, the code just writes one byte at a time, skipping the loop to save some time (this is called 'loop unrolling')

Comment: Guess they could have optimized it for 4 byte boundaries too.

Comment: Maybe, although the check itself might have been too expensive to make a real difference on average.

Comment: `var data = new byte[128];
long num = 0x1234567890ABCDEF;
fixed (byte* p = data)
{
    *(long*)(p + 1) = num;
    *(long*)(p + 10) = num;
}`Without pointer aligned, this code works well.